# Logstash not connecting elasticsearch?

Tags: http, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am running ELK setup on a single machine. Everything was working fine untill I switched off my internet connection.

My logstash console shows this error when I switch off Internet connection:

```
log4j, [2014-11-27T10:31:57.480]  WARN: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty: [logstash-HP-Pro] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x7a124750]], closing connection
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:465)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:457)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:670)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.connect(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:574)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.connect(Channels.java:634)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.connect(AbstractChannel.java:207)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:229)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.connect(ClientBootstrap.java:182)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToChannels(NettyTransport.java:705)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:647)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.connectToNode(NettyTransport.java:615)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNode(TransportService.java:129)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.innerJoinCluster(ZenDiscovery.java:338)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery.access$500(ZenDiscovery.java:79)
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.ZenDiscovery$1.run(ZenDiscovery.java:286)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

**EDIT**
Logstash output config:

```
output {

        elasticsearch { host => localhost }
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

So it seams it's unable to connect to ES server.

So is an internet connection be required always?? I am new to the setup.

Comment: Please add your Logstash output configuration to the question.

Comment: @MagnusBäck: I have added the config.

Comment: Two ideas: your machine releases 'localhost' when the network is disabled (check ifconfig to see if it's still there) and/or elasticsearch is not listening on localhost (but rather an external IP address).

Comment: Rhetorical question: why would you build a centralized log file management system that contained only one machine that couldn't be reached by anyone?